# Can't get a custom edit form to save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to have a form to just edit one field for my user's model that is separate from the scaffold generated _form.erb.

The form will show but it will not save. When I modify the def in the controller with a respond_to block, the form is bypassed and I just get the record shown.

employee_supervisor_edit.html.erb has `<%= render 'employee_supervisor_form' %>`

routes.rb contains `match '/employee_supervisor_edit/:id' => 'users#employee_supervisor_edit' , via: [:get, :post ]`

the form is _employee_supervisor_form.erb

users_controller.rb has

```
  def employee_supervisor_edit
    @users = User.all

    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

I also have have the following in my users controller.

```
  def user_params
 #  params.require(:user).permit(:login,
                           params.permit(:login,
                           :group_strings,
                           :name,
                           :ou_strings,
                           :email,
                           :active_employee,
                           :last_name,
                           :first_name,
                           :is_supervisor,
                           :@supervisor_id)
end
```

end

If I comment out the whole respond_to block, the form appears but no data is saved. If I put the respond_to block in, then the form is bypassed and it goes right to the show method.

I'm not sure if the problem is related to getting the following error if I use `params.require(:user).permit(:login,` instead of  `params.permit(:login,`

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#employee_supervisor_edit
param is missing or the value is empty: user

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:134:in `user_params'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in `block in employee_supervisor_edit'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:15:in `employee_supervisor_edit'
```

==========  added ==============

I have the following associations in my user.rb

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "supervisor_id"
  belongs_to :supervisor, class_name: "User"
```

======== added : =====================

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


   User Login:  <%= @user.login %><br>
   User Name:   <%= @user.name %> <br>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :active_employee %>
          <%= f.check_box :active_employee  %>
    </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :supervisor %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:supervisor_id, User.order('name'), :id, :name, prompt: true)%>

  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Show your `employee_supervisor_edit` method from `users_controller.rb`. If the error is complaining about a specific method, it's usually a good idea to look at that method.

Comment: Can you please post the erb template?

Comment: @MarsAtomic - The method is posted as the first large code block in my original post.

Comment: @BillWatts  - If you were looking for the form itself, I added that to the bottom of my original post. Please let me know if you were looking for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from my data. Since I am in the development process, I don't have all the error checking I need in place. Null fields or associations pointing to non existent records cause errors where it isn't always obvious (at least to me) that the problem is the data, not the code itself.

I went in with an sql editor and made sure that the contents causing the issues were not set to null and that the columns such as supervisor_id were pointing to actual existing records, not records that were deleted.

I changed `params.permit(:login,` back to `params.require(:user).permit(:login,` and now the form is saving as expected.

My next step will be to add validations for input and some error checking for the index and show methods. For the long term, I think that I need to become more proficient with testing as that might show areas that could cause these types of issues.